# Find the maximum element of an subordinate set and a subset.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Hello guys I'm practicing for my discrete mathematics exam and I'm stuck on this exercise. It goes like this:
Let (S, α) be a subordinate set and A is a subset of S. Find the maximum element of the set A.

Comment: What is a subordinate set?

Comment: @ChristianF an ordered set maybe. English isn't my main language so i just google translated the word.

Comment: You can't use a translator to translate technical terms. Locate the Wikipedia page in your native language and change it to English on the side menu. You can also write the question in your native language too.

Comment: What is $\alpha$?  With so little given it has to be a matter of definition.  Can $A$ be empty?  If $A$ can be *any* set its maximum can be any element.  Must $A$ have a maximum element at all?  Is that part of what it means for $S$ to be a "subordinate set"?  What *is* the question even asking?  Did you translate "subset" correctly?  As written, out of context, I don't think this question actually makes any sense.

Comment: @fleablood By subordinate i meant ordered set i just saw it on Wikipedia. And that's all that is given and no i didn't write subset wrong. A is subset of S. And that's all the question asks and gives to work with nothing more.

Comment: I mean, why isn't the answer $\max A$ good enough?  I can't see that there is or *can* be any information that can give us a better answer, but obviously that answer is not worthy of having a question.

Comment: @Leaf If it is as you say, then the question makes no sense because $A$ doesn't necessary have a maximum. For instance let $S=\mathbb R=A$ and $\alpha=\leq$.

Comment: All I can think of is "the maximimum of $A$ is an element, $a \in A$ so that if $b \in A$ then $b \alpha a$".  That is a definition.  There is no way to determine if such an element will actually exist or not, nor which element it will actually be.

Comment: You  call this an "exercise"?  Did you translate *that* correctly?  Is this an actual problem with a solution?  Or is this a question about notation and definition?  The maximum element of $A$ is $\max A$ and it is the element, $a$ of $A$ so that for any other element $b\in A$ then $a \alpha b$ if there *is* such an element.  That is all that can be said.  We don't have any information to say anything more.  This is likes asking "Let A be a book.  What is the best sentence of A?"